# React Native - Context API not working with react-native-navigation (wix)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

My React Native application uses react-native-navigation (wix) and Context API to store variables in the global context.
The Router class is responsible for navigation between screens

Router.js

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

export default class Router {

    static get HOME_STACK_NAME() { return 'HomeStack'; }
    static get HOME_SCREEN() { return 'HomeScreen'; }
    static get SIDE_MENU_SCREEN() { return 'SideMenuScreen'; }
    static get CONFIG_SCREEN() { return 'ConfigScreen'; }

    static get HOME_STACK() {
        return {
            sideMenu: {
                center: {
                    stack: {
                        id: this.HOME_STACK_NAME,
                        children: [
                            {
                                component: {
                                    name: 'HomeScreen'
                                }
                            }

                        ]
                    }
                },
                left: {
                    component: {
                        name: 'SideMenuScreen'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static goToHomeScreen() {
        Navigation.setRoot({root: this.HOME_STACK});
    }

    static goToScreen(stack, screenId, passProps, resetRoot) {
        if (resetRoot) {
            Navigation.setRoot({root: stack});
        }
        let stackId = '';
        if (stack.stack && stack.stack.id) {
            stackId = stack.stack.id;
        } else {
            stackId = stack.sideMenu.center.stack.id;
        }
        Navigation.push(stackId, {
            component: {
                name: screenId,
                passProps: passProps,
                options: {
                    sideMenu: {
                        left: {
                            visible: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

AppContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const AppContext = createContext({});

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
    }, [credentials]);

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ credentials, setCredentials }}>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};
  
export { AppContext, AppContextProvider  };
```

Index.js wraps screens with context and redirects to the HomeScreen screen

index.js

```
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";
import SideMenuScreen from './src/screen/SideMenuScreen'
import HomeScreen from './src/screen/HomeScreen';
import ConfigScreen from './src/screen/config/ConfigScreen';
import Router from './src/navigation/Router';
import { AppContextProvider } from './src/context/AppContext';

const contextWrapper = (Component) => {
    const WrappedComponent = (props) => (
      <AppContextProvider>
        <Component {...props} />
      </AppContextProvider>
    );

    return WrappedComponent;
};

Navigation.registerComponent(Router.SIDE_MENU_SCREEN, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(contextWrapper(SideMenuScreen)), () => SideMenuScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent(Router.HOME_SCREEN, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(contextWrapper(HomeScreen)), () => HomeScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent(Router.CONFIG_SCREEN, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(contextWrapper(ConfigScreen)), () => ConfigScreen);

Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
    topBar: {
        title: {
            alignment: 'left'
        }
    }
});

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(async () => {
    Navigation.setRoot({root: Router.HOME_STACK});
});
```

HomeScreen fetches user credentials and stores in context

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
    SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";
import Router from '../navigation/Router';
import { AppContext } from '../context/AppContext';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

    static contextType = AppContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const { setCredentials } = this.context

        AccessService.getCredenciais()
            .then(credentials => {
                setCredentials(credentials);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.toString());
                Toast.show('Erro', error.toString());
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
```

After the HomeScreen is loaded, the user chooses the option in the app menu to go to the ConfigScreen screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
    SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";
import { AppContext } from '../../context/AppContext';

export default class ConfigScreen extends Component {

    static contextType = AppContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const { credentials } = this.context;
        console.log('credentials: ' + JSON.stringify(credentials));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
           </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }

}
```

In the componentDidMount method of ConfigScreen, console.log prints empty credentials, as if they were not loaded into HomeScreen. Apparently every screen registered in react-native-navigation has its own empty context. I would like variables loaded in context within HomeScreen to have their values preserved and to be accessible for subsequent screens. How to solve this problem? Can you help me?